# Eigenvalues/Eigenvectors of operators on a Fock space

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Suppose we have an operator defined by

$$S_0 = 1, \ S_n = 1_2^{\otimes n-1}\otimes X^n,$$

where $X = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix}$, $1_2$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix and $n>0$. Then we define the operator
$$S : = \bigoplus_{n\geq 0} S_n.$$
How can we find the eigenvalues of this operator? I understand that in this specfic case of $X$, the eigenvalues of $S_n$ for $n$ odd are $-1, 1$ with multiplicity $2n$ and for $n>0$ even the only eigenvalue is $1$ with multiplicity $4n$. But how can we talk about the eigenvalues of $S$ given that it is an infinite direct sum?

I am also also interested from there the eigenvectors too but I can see this would follow from the eigenvalues, and also if we can extend this discussion to general unitary $X$.

Comment: When you say "$1$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix", does that include the $1$'s inside your definition of $X$?

Comment: Ah, no - sorry. In the definition of $X$ they are just scalars. I will edit to make it more clear

Comment: $S_n$ acts on $H_n=(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes (n-1)}\otimes(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes n}\cong\mathbb{C}^{2^{2n-1}}$ ($n\neq 0$) and you take direct sum of the $H_n$ as your Fock space (presumably you want to take the Hilbertian direct sum, i.e., complete the usual direct sum under the inner product norm).  Then $\bigoplus S_n$ acts on $\bigoplus H_n$ and we can talk about eigenvalues, eigenvectors.  For general unitary $X$ with eigenvalue not a root of unity, you get other parts of the continuous spectrum coming in too.